# How to resize a column back to 8.43 in excel if the column is blank

Tags: excel, vba

Good Afternoon everyone,

Quick question, I have this

`Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Value In Target.Columns
        Worksheets(Sh.Name).Columns(Value.Column).AutoFit
        Next Value
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub`
and it works great it does exactly what I want which is resize the column based on whatever value is typed or pasted but as time has gone by I was wondering would it be possible to come up with a few lines so that if I erase a value the column go back to its original size which is 8.43 I'm quite unsure if this would be possible.

Anyone up to the challenge?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: if you add before Autofit the line ...Columns(Value.Column).ColumnWidth = 8.43 it's work.

Comment: Perfect simple does what I wanted I had actually tried something similar but it didn't work perhaps it was because I was trying something more elaborate haveing excel analyzing the cells and if empty resize it but this works perfectly.

Thanks,
                                                 Tom Ruiz
                                                 CEO LRD CORP.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon to anyone who founds this question usefull just so that everyone can use the code here is how it should look like so that the columns resize to the original size if you delete the content in such column.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Value In Target.Columns
        Columns(Value.Column).ColumnWidth = 8.43
        Worksheets(Sh.Name).Columns(Value.Column).AutoFit
        Next Value
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```